# MSBuild doing OctoPack before Publish

Tags: function, azure, msbuild, compiled, octopack

I have a C# .NET v4.6.1 compiled Azure Function, I am using [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/1.0.2) and I deploy it using my usual CI/CD Pipeline.

That being, a TeamCity MSBuild Build Step to create an OctoPack (because I have installed the [OctoPack 3.6.3 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/3.6.3). 
I then publish the resulting **.nupkg* file to Octopus and Create a Release.

This is how I do all my Azure App Services, however as is nicely described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643347/azure-function-returns-error-no-job-functions-found-try-making-your-job-classe), compiled Azure Functions create a few extra files/folders when they are published to describe the entry point for the Function.

I can see (in the TeamCity build logs) that these extra files/folders are created by MSBuild (15.3.409.57025) but only AFTER it has prepared the OctoPack. Meaning my OctoPack artifact does not contain the necessary function specific folder(s) with the *function.json* file nor the *functionsSdk.out*.

I have managed to get around this issue by doing an extra TeamCity NuGet Pack Build Step to build the OctoPack again. I also had to create a **.nuspec* file in the project root, where I tell NuGet Pack to include everything (see below) because using just the **.csproj* file also ignored the extra folder/files.

```
<files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net461\**\*.*" />
</files>
```

This works because it runs after the MSBuild Step and the extra folders/files are present. It will also be robust enough to support other Functions when are added to the Project going forward.

The need for this extra step and the *.nuspec file seems unnecessary. Can anyone see where I went wrong and why MSBuild seems to have the sequence of Publish and OctoPak wrong?

Comment: Does my answer helped you to resolve the issue?

Comment: The same issue here. I tried specifying the files to include, but an error showed up `OCTONUGET Could not find a part of the path ***`

Answer (score 0):

1. This could be a reason:

> If the  section exists, OctoPack by default won't attempt to
>   automatically add any extra files to your package, so you'll need to
>   be explicit about which files you want to include. You can override
>   this behavior with /p:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles=true which will
>   instruct OctoPack to package a combination of files using its
>   conventions, and those defined by your  section.
>
> https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/creating-packages/nuget-packages/using-octopack

2. Another idea — broken `.csproj` file. Please check it.

   Maybe, during the merge these two lines were reordered:

   ```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
   <Import Project="..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.3\build\OctoPack.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\OctoPack.3.6.3\build\OctoPack.targets')" />
   ```

   There should be `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` first. Order matters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vladimir, because it is a compiled Azure Function the project file is not a typical .NET Standard .csproj so there are no import statements.

 `code`
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: OctoPack running after publish

```
<Target Name="SetRunOctoPack">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <RunOctoPack>true</RunOctoPack>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="AfterPublish" DependsOnTargets="SetRunOctoPack">
  <CallTarget Targets="OctoPack"/>
</Target>
```